# Как дать описание файлу в Java

Tags: java, файлы, шифрование

Пишу программу, который должна шифровать файлы. Я получаю path файла с помощью JFileChooser, получаю path output файла и через поток FileInputStream читаю байты, которые шифруются и выводятся в файл потоком CipherOutputStream вот часть этого кода.

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    SecretKeySpec skey = new SecretKeySpec(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(Dispatcher.getK()), "AES");
    cipher.init(mod, skey);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    int numBytes;
    if(mod == Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE) {
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(outputFile, cipher);
        while ((numBytes = inputFile.read(bytes)) != -1){
            cos.write(bytes, 0, numBytes);
        }
        cos.flush();
        cos.close();
        inputFile.close();
    }
    if (mod == Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE){
        CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(inputFile, cipher);
        while ((numBytes = cis.read(bytes)) != -1){
            outputFile.write(bytes, 0, numBytes);
        }
        outputFile.flush();
        outputFile.close();
        cis.close();
    }
```

Проблема в том, что при расшифровке файла получается файл с неизвестным расширением, и пользователь вручную должен поставить то расширение, которое изначально было у файла.
Дк вот, вопрос в том, можно ли при шифровании файла в его описание или ещё куда добавить то самое расширение, чтобы потом приписать его при расшифровке файла.
Заранее спасибо, рад любой помощи.

Comment: Вам нужно придумать, как вначало потока вставить имя файла. Например: первые 2 байта - длина имени, дальше само имя файла, дальше - контент файла. При расшифровке нужно будет это считать.

Comment: Я вижу два варианта: первый сохранять в файл с таким же расширением, второй зарезервировать первые несколько байт под расширение и считывать из них

Comment: А можно ли вообще как-то сделать описание файла из программы, просто ради интереса. Там написать кампанию, создавшую файл, мета данные вообщем какие-то вставить?

Comment: Можно попробовать через атрибуты файла.

Comment: То, что вы имеете ввиду под метаданными - это часть ехе, или dll файла, они содержатся внутри самого файла. Через аттрибуты файловой системы вы много не вставите. + Они не скопируются при переносе файла.

Comment: Вообще рекомендую посмотреть в сторону *сложных* архивов. Прежде всего это *tar* (можно также присмотреться к *zip*). А уже на этот архив накладывать шифрование. Вот тут [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6997935/5506820) создание *tar*.